# how can i create project by chromium gn tools?

Tags: chromium, pdfium, gn

install depot_tool then following the [gn guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/tools/gn/) and [standalone guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/tools/gn/+/HEAD/docs/standalone.md), but i always get error "gn.py: Could not find checkout in any parent of the current path."

so my problem is :

1. how to create the gn project which is not using chromium sub project, eg: only one function like helloword?
2. how to create the gn project which is using chromium sub project like v8/pdfium, eg: one console project is using pdfium to read pdf page count.?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure from the error you describe but it sounds like you don't have a `.gn` file in the root.

I recently started getting into `gn` and made a simple starter project: https://github.com/aellerton/experiment-learn-gn

The first thing I didn't expect was the need to have a root `.gn` file, and that the file needs to point to the root config: https://github.com/aellerton/experiment-learn-gn/blob/master/.gn

The second thing I didn't expect was the need to provide an entire toolchain. I kind of like this now as it gives me full power. I used this one here, by making it a git submodule as the author suggests: https://github.com/timniederhausen/gn-build

Then building a trivial Hello World console program was straightforward.